# Any working Twitter API client for Common Lisp?

Tags: twitter, lisp, common-lisp

I was just trying to use [cl-twitter](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-twitter/), installed it first using [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/) and I got this error when executing examples from its documentation:

```
The function TWITTER:AUTHENTICATE-USER is undefined.
```

Is this software up to date? Or it's just that the documentation is not? Are there any other working Common Lisp libs for Twitter API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot offer a full client library, but for the authentication part of it, [cl-oauth](https://github.com/skypher/cl-oauth) works well.  See [this piece of code](https://github.com/hanshuebner/planetwit/blob/master/planetwit.lisp#L53) for a usage example.